# Omega limit set on the unit sphere

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

We can take, for example, the following field $X=(-y+xz^2,x+yz^2,-zx^2-zy^2)$ that models what the following image requests:

[image]

I have shown that $\omega_X(p)=\{Equator\}$ where $p\in\mathbb S^2-\{P_N,P_S\}$ and understand that the field $Y$ vanishes clearly at the equator, but I don't know how to prove that the set $\omega_Y(p)=\{Equator\}$ for any regular point of $Y$. Any ideas I can follow please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the equator, the trajectories of the vector field $Y$ are the same as for $X$, only with a different time parametrization.

Comment: I was thinking something like that since $\varphi(p)\neq 0$ for $p\in\mathbb S^2-\{Equator\}$ but I don't know how to justify it, could you give me some light on that?

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013409/preserving-orbits-by-multiplication-with-a-non-vanishing-function

Comment: I was looking at the link you sent and also Carmen Chicone's book, but both take a positive function, in my case I have a non-negative function that only nulls at the equator, by removing the equator I no longer have a continuous function. How can I surf that problem? Or maybe I'm not seeing something obvious I'm sorry.

Comment: Perhaps what I am not seeing is the following: Taking each upper and lower hemisphere separately, as a domain, where $\varphi>0$ is continuous since its domain is in both cases it is connected, so everything would work fine. Is it really that?

Comment: Yes, since the equator is a closed orbit for $X$ and consists only of equilibria for $Y$, no other solution curves cross the equator. So you can look at the two hemispheres separately, and there $X$ and $Y$ have the same orbits.