# How to solve this ODE with respect to t?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE
$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt} = -y\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = -x\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\
\end{equation}
$$
can be solved through dividing the two formula and get $x^2 + y^2 = C$ for some constant $C$. But how to solve for the relationship with $t$?

Comment: So $y=\pm\sqrt{C-x^2}$. Substitute into the first ODE to and solve for $x$, and from there for $y$.

Comment: It's $x^2-y^2=C$

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013409/preserving-orbits-by-multiplication-with-a-non-vanishing-function