# Solving a coupled system of first order homogeneous differential equations with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, circles

Given the coupled system of first order homogeneous ordinary differential equations with variable coefficients.
$$    
\frac{dx}{dt} = a(t)z(t)
$$
$$
\frac{dz}{dt} = -a(t)x(t)
$$

How is the general solution below derived?

$$
x(t) = c_1 \cos\left(\int_1^t a(\tau) d\tau \right)+c_2 \sin\left(\int_1^t a(\tau) d\tau\right)
$$

$$
z(t) = -c_1 \sin\left(\int_1^t a(\tau) d\tau \right)+c_2 \cos\left(\int_1^t a(\tau) d\tau\right)
$$

I thought it might be something like guessing the solution takes the form

$$
x(t) = c_1 \cos\left(f(t)\right)+c_2 \sin\left(f(t)\right)
$$

$$
z(t) = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{df}{dt}\right)} \frac{dx}{dt} = -c_1 \sin\left(f(t)\right)+c_2 \cos\left(f(t)\right)
$$

And $\frac{df}{dt} = a(t)$

But I imagine there is a general approach to this type of problem?

Comment: This should help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013409/preserving-orbits-by-multiplication-with-a-non-vanishing-function, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3890957/show-that-orbitally-equivalent-autonomous-systems-do-have-same-orbits/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Notice that
$$\phantom{(\ast)} \qquad (x^2 + z^2)' = 2 x x' + 2 z z' = 2 x (az) + 2 (-ax) z = 0 , \qquad (\ast)$$
so $(x(t), z(t))$ traces out an arc of a circle, say of radius $R \geq 0$, centered at the origin in the $xz$-plane. Using the standard parameterization of that circle gives that
$$x(t) = R \cos \theta(t), \qquad z(t) = R \sin \theta(t)$$
for some function $\theta(t)$.

> Substituting our expressions in $\theta$ back in $(\ast)$ gives (provided that $R \neq 0$) that $$\theta' = -a,$$ hence $$\theta = -\int a \,dt$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint, is $y(t)$ meant to be $z(t)$ in the parameterization or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it should be $z(t)$---just a force of habit.